# How to position the caret where the user clicked in the cell

Tags: java, javafx, position, tableview, caret

I want my editable TableView to behave exactly as an Excel sheet would. This means that double clicking on any cell should put it into its editing state and position the caret where the user clicked in the textfield that is shown on edit (or at the end of the text if the user clicks anywhere after the end of the text).

As far as I know the weirdly named method `positionCaret(int)` is the method used to position the caret in a `TextField`. But this position seems to be specified in chars and not in the x position value that you can get from the `MouseEvent.getX()`.

Moreover, just trying out `positionCaret(int)` with e.g. dummy value "2", doesn't quite work anyway. Sometimes the caret is positioned after the second character, and sometimes it's just placed at the beginning of the text. Since which one it is seems to be completely random, I'm guessing it's some kind of thread issue.

I've provided an MCVE below. The code for the editable cell is a slightly modified version of example 12-11 from the [TableView tutorial on docs.oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestEditableTable extends Application {
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        TableView<ObservableList<StringProperty>> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setEditable(true);
        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

        // Makes sure that the cell isn't put into editing mode unless it is double clicked.
        table.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

                // Only necessary in windows 7.
                if (event.isControlDown()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (table.getEditingCell() == null) {
                    table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                }
            }
        });

        // Dummy columns
        ObservableList<String> columns = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4",
                "Column5");

        // Dummy data
        ObservableList<StringProperty> row1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new SimpleStringProperty("Cell1"),
                new SimpleStringProperty("Cell2"), new SimpleStringProperty("0"), new SimpleStringProperty("Cell4"),
                new SimpleStringProperty("0"));
        ObservableList<StringProperty> row2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new SimpleStringProperty("Cell1"),
                new SimpleStringProperty("Cell2"), new SimpleStringProperty("1"), new SimpleStringProperty("Cell4"),
                new SimpleStringProperty("2"));
        ObservableList<ObservableList<StringProperty>> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(row1, row2);

        for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++) {
            final int j = i;
            TableColumn<ObservableList<StringProperty>, String> col = new TableColumn<>(columns.get(i));
            col.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().get(j));

            col.setCellFactory(e -> new EditingCell());

            table.getColumns().add(col);
        }

        table.setItems(data);

        Scene scene = new Scene(table);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    /**
     * An editable cell.
     */
    class EditingCell extends TableCell<ObservableList<StringProperty>, String> {

        private TextField textField;

        @Override
        public void startEdit() {
            if (!isEmpty()) {
                super.startEdit();
                createTextField();
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(textField);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelEdit() {
            super.cancelEdit();

            setText(getItem());
            setGraphic(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if (isEditing()) {
                    if (textField != null) {
                        textField.setText(item);
                    }
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(textField);
                } else {
                    setText(item);
                    setGraphic(null);
                }
            }
        }

        // Instantiates the text field.
        private void createTextField() {
            textField = new TextField(getItem());
            textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
            textField.setPadding(new Insets(0));

            // If the user defocus the textfield the edit should be commited. However, this only works properly if the focus is lost to another cell on the same row as far as I can tell.
            textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) {
                    if (!arg2) {
                        commitEdit(textField.getText());
                    }
                }
            });

            setOnMousePressed(e -> {
                // Gets the x coordinate of the cursor relative to the text field. Isn't used at the moment, but might prove useful.
                Double x = e.getX();

                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    // The text field isn't focused unless we do this.
                    textField.requestFocus();

                    // Just testing positionCaret with some dummy value, doesn't seem to work properly.
                    textField.positionCaret(2);
                });
            });


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A `TableView` is not really intended to be a spreadsheet. You might want to look at [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/), and in particular the [SpreadsheetView](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetView.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did try the SpreadsheetView, and as far as I can tell there's some functionalities that is very hard or impossible to implement using that class (e.g. a adding filters, maybe?). I.M.O (and lot of other people's as well, see e.g. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8089514) an editable table should behave as a spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe consider using a table cell implementation that is simply always in "editing mode": i.e. it always just displays a text field, which is bound bidirectionally to the appropriate property. This is similar to the way the standard `CheckBoxTableCell` is implemented. Like that cell implementation, the cell never goes into and out of "editing mode", so the `startEdit`, `commitEdit`, and `cancelEdit` methods are never invoked, and `CellEditEvent`s are never fired on the column, but the data displayed is just constantly synced with the properties in the model.

Here's a sample:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyStringWrapper;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AlwaysEditingTable extends Application {

    private final static int NUM_COLUMNS = 10 ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TableView<List<String>> table = new TableView<>();
        FilteredList<List<String>> filteredList = populateTableData(table);

        for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < NUM_COLUMNS; colIndex++) {
            final int c = colIndex ;
            table.getColumns().add(column("Column "+(colIndex+1), 
                    (List<String> row) -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(row.get(c)), 
                    (List<String> row, String newText) -> row.set(c, newText)));
        }



        Button debugButton = new Button("Print content");
        debugButton.setOnAction(e -> 
            table.getItems().stream().map(row -> String.join("\t", row)).forEach(System.out::println)
        );

        TextField filter = new TextField();
        filter.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
            filteredList.setPredicate(row -> row.stream().filter(data -> data.startsWith(newValue)).findAny().isPresent())
        );
        filter.setPromptText("Enter filter");

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table, filter, null, debugButton, null);
        BorderPane.setMargin(debugButton, new Insets(10));
        BorderPane.setAlignment(debugButton, Pos.CENTER);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 880, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property, BiConsumer<S,String> updater) {
        TableColumn<S,T> column = new TableColumn<>(title);
        column.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        column.setCellFactory(c -> new AlwaysEditingCell<S,T>(updater));
        return column ;
    }

    private FilteredList<List<String>> populateTableData(TableView<List<String>> table) {

        ObservableList<List<String>> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList() ;
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 30 ; i++) {
            List<String> row = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < NUM_COLUMNS ; colIndex++) {
                row.add("Data ["+(colIndex+1)+", "+i+"]");
            }
            data.add(row);
        }

        FilteredList<List<String>> filteredList = new FilteredList<>(data);
        table.setItems(filteredList);
        return filteredList ;
    }



    public static class AlwaysEditingCell<S,T> extends TableCell<S,T> {

        private final TextField textField ;

        /**
         * 
         * @param updater A function that acts on the current row value and the 
         * text in the text field to update the row value according to the new 
         * text. This function is invoked whenever the text in the text field changes.
         */
        public AlwaysEditingCell(BiConsumer<S,String> updater) {

            textField = new TextField();

            this.emptyProperty().addListener((obs, wasEmpty, isNowEmpty) -> {
                if (isNowEmpty) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    setGraphic(textField);
                }
            });

            textField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, newText) -> 
                updater.accept(getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()), newText));
        }

        @Override
        public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                String value = item.toString() ;
                if (! value.equals(textField.getText())) {
                    textField.setText(value);
                }
                setGraphic(textField);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this! The only potential problem I can see with this approach at the moment is navigating up and down the table with the arrow buttons. The solution I used earlier was invoking `getTableView().getFocusModel().focusAboveCell()` for navigating up and the `focusBelowCell()` counterpart for navigating down. But it doesn't seem to have any effect in this implementation. The caret just stays in the current text field.

Comment: Probably the text field is consuming the key events (since it has focus as soon as you focus the cell). I'd experiment with adding an event **filter** to the text field (or cell) which detects keys and implements some navigation, using the focus model as you describe.

Comment: I guess I'll leave this thread open for further answers since your answer - although very helpful - doesn't answer the actual question. Is that OK?

Comment: This does not appear to work if I put the `ObservableList` into a `FilteredList` and add filtering functionality to the table. It does filter correctly at first, but when you remove the filter all of the rows or some of them gets the same value and gets bound to each other. Should it be possible to add a filter to this solution or do I need to use something else if I want filtering possibilites?

Comment: Add a listener to the `itemProperty()` as well. The issue in that case is that, when the filter is removed, for some cells the item changes but the index remains unchanged (so the listener on the index doesn't get invoked).

Comment: So if I understand this correctly: The issue is that the cell index first changes to e.g. -1 during filtering (I guess this is the case for cells on rows that doesn't match the filter?) which will remove the previous bind it had for its old index, but not add a new one since index is -1. Then the value of the cell might change, but the value of the textfield will not be updated since it isn't currently bound to anything, correct? If this is the case, then what should I do in the `itemProperty()` listener? I've tried inter alia `textField.setText(newValue)`, without result.

Comment: I was envisioning a situation where, say, the item in cell with index 2 gets filtered. So now that cell still has index 2, but item number 2 is what was previously item number 3. The cell has to display that item, but its index hasn't changed. Setting the text in the listener should work...

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. With the setup I had, it's impossible to unbind the text property when the item changes, as there's no reasonable way to get hold of the old property. I guess the easiest fix is a listener on the text field instead of the binding. I updated the example.

Comment: I suspected something like that was the issue! Sorry for my ignorance, but is there any way to reproduce your new example using an Item class wrapping an ObservableList and providing a `getValueProperty(index)` instead since I want my table to have about 10 different columns? After a few hours of trying a wasn't able to do this my self, probably due to the fact that I'm having trouble understanding the BiConsumer interface.

Comment: The method reference `Item::setValue1` is equivalent to the lambda expression `(Item item, String newText) -> item.setValue1(newText);`. The docs for `BiConsumer` are [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiConsumer.html). I updated the code to use a general list instead of a specific model class.